# swift how to add data from remote url to local realm database

Tags: ios, swift, database, import, realm

Sorry, maybe description of my problem is unclear.

I'm making an app that allows to download several dictionaries or vocabularies ("ru - en", "en -  ru", "sinonims", "definitions" etc). I'm going to save everything in single realm db. It's already working with pre-build set of data.

As there are new dictionaries appeared, I want users to be able to download new dictionaries, that will be imported to realm

I'm pretty new to realm, and googled a lot, but as I see on stackoverflow -> that the only option is to download new data in CSV or json data, then parse it and insert into realm by the loop. Or maybe there is any more "swifty - realm" solution, that allows to download compacted realm, and import it to local database? I already have converter that can create realms in needed format, but I do not understand how to download them and "inject"

[image]

Comment: You need to take care of converting downloaded data to Realm model objects yourself. There are several ways to convert textual representation of objects to native Swift objects, for JSON there is the Codable protocol built in to Swift 4 or the ObjectMapper framework amongst others.

Comment: so, if I want to import new array of objects from remote url, I should download JSON or CSV at first?

So I can't download "compacted realm file" and import it to my local db?

Comment: Since you explicitly asked JSON or CSV, I assumed you need to convert objects from those formats to Realm format. If what you actually need is exporting a full Realm database file from one device and importing it to another device, that should be feasible as well, but I've never tried it. If you actually need to export/import your Realm to a universal format (such as JSON or CSV, have a look at [Realm cocoa converter](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter).

Comment: I've updated my question.